# Angular 2 - How to set a template reference variables value to "true"

Tags: angular, angular2-template

With the following code, using a template reference variable `#open`:

```
<label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#slide" #open (click)="open.value = !open.value">
...
</label>
```

`#open` is false on page load, how can I set it to true?
(Toggling value on click works fine.)

Tried this, but it doesnt work:

`#open="true"` and `#open.value="true"`

Comment: your solution should work, i have tested this

Comment: Consider using attributes that are part of the HTML element you"re using. `label` doesn't contain a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using template reference variable it stores the entire element when you declare in it

using click event you can get

```
(click)="open ? open = false : open = true;"
```

Comment: Your answer will only confuse him more. Templates variables aren't variables like in the typescript code : they refer to HTML elements. You can't set their value like that : if you want to do that, consider creating a class variable, not a template variable.